# Is there replacement for SumatraPDF?

Tags: pdf, viewers, winedt

I am using SumatraPDF as PDF viewer for WinEdt. SumatraPDF provides direct and inverse search. That's good. However SumatraPDF cannot show video embedded with media9 package. That's bad. Is there a better replacement for SumatraPDF?

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of SumatraPDF under Windows is that it does not lock the PDF, so LaTeX can compile an new PDF while SumatraPDF shows the PDF.

If you need really advanced PDF features, I'm afraid there is no way around Acrobat and closing the PDF each time before compiling. I remember a discussion some years ago how to prevent Acrobat from locking the PDF, but according from an answer here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/Acrobat-Reader/Disable-file-lock-on-Adobe-Reader-DC-Windows-10/m-p/9164368 that isn't possible.

Comment: Microsoft Store suggests lot of PDF viewers/editors, some of which are free. Acrobat is not a solution as you explaned.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I see, but as far as I know, there is no other PDF viewer that does not lock the PDF. // EDIT: Seems I'm wrong: https://blog.stefan-macke.com/2016/01/04/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-foxit-reader-without-exclusively-blocking-the-files/

Comment: Acrobat is terrible.  If I open a PDF with it, even if I close it and open a new PDF, I have to give the tex-file a new name before compiling, because Acrobat often keep the file lock on for a long time, often until next reboot.

Comment: @Sveinung I don't use Acrobat Viewer -- but if you'd like to have moving 3D objects inside the PDF, the choice probably is _very_ limited.

Comment: But still I think Acrobat could free up the file locks when you close a file.